# How can I use relation with Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a site to store series.

My database contains a Programs table and a Category table.
The category table has an `ID` and a `name`.

The Programs table contains all the information about this program and the category id associated with it.

I have a `/category/$categoryName` function.

I would like, via the `user-specified $categoryName,` to display all programs that are in this category.

```
public function category(string $categoryName):Response{
    $categoryInfos = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Category::class)
        ->findOneByName($categoryName);

    $categoryID = $categoryInfos['id'];
```

gives me ->

> "Cannot use object of type App\Entity\Category as array"

Once I have the `category ID`, I can display all the programs that belong to that category but

1) I can't retrieve the ID

2) I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler command to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: And what have you tried to debug that problem? As far as I see, `$categoryInfos` is an array of categories. As the error tells you: `$categoryInfos['id']` is not defined

Comment: Of course, I played with findByX and not with findOneByX. The problem is now different, Cannot use object of type App\Entity\Category as array.

That's why I wonder if there is not a simpler way / dedicated to this type of ManyToOne requests.

Comment: I've got it. 
I probably asked for help a little too quickly.
I got stuck on the problem and it tickled me a little...
Thanks anyway ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is an array so for accessing the id, first you need to access to first element of the array then you can access the id:

```
$categoryID = $categoryInfos[0]['id'];
```

if you know that you will have an unique result so you can use setMaxResult:

```
$categoryInfos = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Category::class)
    ->findByName($categoryName)
    ->setMaxResult(1);
```

and the result must be like:

```
object(App\Entity\Category)#501 (2) { ["id":"App\Entity\Category":private]=> int(1) ["name":"App\Entity\Category":private]=> string(7) "Horreur" }
```

finally you can use your own code to access the id:

```
$categoryID = $categoryInfos['id'];
```

if you still can not access to id, maybe the id is a **private** property and you can use **getter** functions, for accessing to the id, use **getId()** or for name use **getName()** and etc.

```
$categoryID = $categoryInfos->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{categoryName}", name="category")
 */
public function category(string $categoryName): Response
{
    $categoryInfos = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Category::class)
        ->findOneByName($categoryName);

    $categoryInfos->getId();

    return $this->render('home.html.twig');
}
```

Well, that's it.